# Is it possible to visit and modify AST nodes via spock extension?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

Spock has great feature: [Argument Constraints](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#argument-constraints).
And I trying to transplant this feature for my task:

```
// JSON body template for comparsion
[
    id: _ as Long,
    inn: !null,
    name: _ as String,
    addresses: 1.._ * [city: _ as String, street: _ as String, house: _ as Integer]
]
```

Also Spock allow to extend self via special annotations: [Spock Extensions](http://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensions.html), [AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension](https://code.google.com/p/spock/source/browse/branches/groovy-1.7/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/extension/AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension.java?r=779).

But i can't realise how to modify AST node of Feature via `visitFeatureAnnotation`.
Seems it impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spock doesn't provide any hooks for this. You'd have to write a standard Groovy AST transformation (or fork Spock).